How to get past the Azure Code Search $skip limitation?
Currently using the Azure CodeSearch API.
Making a query, which returns around 7k results (which doesn't sound outrageous).
POST https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=7.1
Authorization: Basic {{PAT64}}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "$top": 1,
  "searchText": "ext: kt"
}

Started implementing pagination, only to receive an exception :
"$Skip parameter should be in the range [0, 1000]. The parameter supplied is [6000]."
That sounds awfully low, especially given that the API returns a maximum of 1k results too.
What method should I use to retrieve those 7k results?
Thanks!

It seems that I might not be the first one to wonder btw, though no answer seems to have come up yet https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/skip-parameter-for-code-search-API-shou/10000280?q=Return+value&stateGroup=active&ftype=idea
